# React and d3-graphviz

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, graphviz

I'm trying to render a graphviz graph from a dotfile in my React Component. I keep running into errors I don't understand. If anyone could shed some light I would be grateful.

```js
import React from 'react';
import dotSrc from '../../assets/visualize_dotfile.dot';
import Viz from 'viz.js';
import * as d3 from 'd3'
import * as d3Graphviz from 'd3-graphviz';


class Visualization extends React.Component {

 setGraph() {
    console.log('DOT source =', dotSrc);
    const dotSrcLines = dotSrc.split('\n');

    d3.select(".graph").graphviz().renderDot(dotSrc);
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="graph">
        {this.setGraph}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Visualization;
```

I've also tried:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import dotSrc from '../../assets/visualize_dotfile.dot';
import Viz from 'viz.js';
import HTMLReactParser from 'react-html-parser';


const graph = Viz({ files: [ { path: dotSrc } ] });

class Visualization extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          {HTMLReactParser(graph)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<Visualization />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

To no avail. Neither Viz nor GraphViz wants to read my dotfile though I'm not sure I'm using the correct syntax either.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

It's not exactly clear what you want to do and what errors you are getting.

This code at least generates a graph from a static string when the button is clicked:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as d3 from 'd3'
import * as d3Graphviz from 'd3-graphviz';

var dotSrc = 'digraph  {a -> b}';

class App extends Component {
 setGraph() {
    console.log('DOT source =', dotSrc);
    d3.select(".graph").graphviz().renderDot(dotSrc);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to magjac&#39;s React hack</h1>
        </header>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/viz.js@1.8.0/viz.js" type="javascript/worker"></script>

        <div className="graph">
        </div>
        <button className="square" onClick={() => this.setGraph()}>
          {'Click me'}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you. :-)

Comment: is any way to refer to viz.js from node_modules instead of going to remote version?

Comment: @lowtech I think there should be, but I haven't been able to find out how . It's on the TODO list (although unfortunately not at the top right now.) for [my own application](https://github.com/magjac/graphviz-visual-editor/blob/master/src/pages/index.js#L476). If you find out how to do it or have any suggestion for supporting it better in [d3-graphviz](https://github.com/magjac/d3-graphviz), please let me know.